# Why does Svelte crash after replacing the dom content in the middle of a transition?

Tags: svelte, web-component, custom-element, svelte-transition

I have a web page where the dom content is changed dynamically. There is a svelte component (in the form of a customElement) that plays a confirmation transition showing a checkmark for 3s and returning back to the original state. This is achieved using `transition:`. If the user navigates (replacing the dom content, not navigating the url), the component still tries to update the transition even though the element is destroyed. The error thrown is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRule')`. This causes the newly generated svelte-button to crash and click events no longer work.

Putting the `<script>` tag import in the snippet-dom that is inserted does not solve the issue. I was thinking this would reset any promises created by the svelte code.

I also found issue [#5268](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5268). In my case what triggers the error and return transition is a `setTimeout`. I have tried clearing the timeout using `onDestroy()` but it does not trigger.

Is it possible to cancel the old promise or disable the transition if the element is no longer present in the dom?

Edit:
[Here is an almost minimal demo project](https://github.com/cascading-jox/svelte-transition-error).

Comment: can you send the code you are working on?

Comment: Sorry yeah, I'll try to create a minimal code example in the weekend.

Comment: @AhmetK I've added a link to a demo project now. Sorry about the delay, I didn't have time until now.

Comment: @cascading-jox Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem with a transition on a custom component.

Comment: @Théophile Sadly I have not. I just removed the transition. Maybe it's time to open an issue...